# Animation to show / hide script using css

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate

I want to add a fade in / fade out effect to a hidden block (id = "help"). How can I animate a block using pure css? Also, I want to animate the link (id = "show) after clicking. Please help and give me some examples.

See my code:

```js
    var showElem = document.getElementById("show");
    var hideElem = document.getElementById("hide");
    var helpDiv = document.getElementById("help");

    helpDiv.style.display = 'none';
    hideElem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    showElem.onclick = function() {
      showElem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      hideElem.style.visibility = 'visible';
      helpDiv.style.display = 'block';
    };

    hideElem .onclick = function() {
      hideElem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      showElem.style.visibility = 'visible';
      helpDiv.style.display = 'none';
    };
```

```css
div#help { 
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" id="show">SHOW</a>
  <a href="#" id="hide">HIDE</a>
  <div id="help"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use the CSS3 'animation' property.
Also, i've noticed you tagged 'jquery', so you can use $('...').slideDown();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $('.help').addClass('sh');
    $(this).css('opacity',0)
    $("#hide").css('opacity',1)
  })

  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $('.help').removeClass('sh');
     $(this).css('opacity',0)
    $("#show").css('opacity',1)
  })
})
```

```css
#hide, #show, .help {
    transition: all 1s;
}
.help { 
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  #hide {
   opacity: 0;
  }

 .sh {
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<a href="#" id="show">SHOW</a>
<a href="#" id="hide">HIDE</a>
<div class="help" class="sh"></div>
```

Comment: Great idea, but i need two links (show and hide). I can't use toggle class

Comment: @Mousebucks can you use addClass an removeClass?

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here you can see the effect of your work :) http://leadomat.com/pluginchat/ I create a plugin that you can paste on any page. Do you know how this piece of code turns into a plugin? I would like to paste it on a page with JS (the maximum simple and short code)

Comment: @Mousebucks you are welcome, i see your plugin.it is nice.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using jQuery:

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0j9qbj7p/4/

**HTML**

```
  <a href="#" id="show">SHOW</a>
  <a href="#" id="hide">HIDE</a>
  <div id="help">Text here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hide, #help{
  display: none;
}

#help{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 400px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$showElem = $('#show');
$hideElem = $('#hide');
$helpElem = $('#help');

    $showElem.click(function(){
        $helpElem.slideDown();
        $hideElem.show();
    });

    $hideElem.click(function(){
        $helpElem.slideUp();
        $hideElem.hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use animations with pure CSS, you have to use '@keyframes' to control the opacity ( in order to simulate fade in / fade out effect) of the box.
Just add this to the top of the CSS file:

```css
@keyframes FadeAnimation {
  from{
      opacity:0;
  }
  to {
      opacity:1;
  }
}
```

But afterwards, you also have to show what item you want to animate by adding this line to your code:

```css
div#help { 
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background:grey /* it is important to give a background color*/
    animation-name: FadeAnimation; /* the name of the keyframes */
    animation-duration:0.5s /* the duration time */
    animation-iteration-count:1; /* how many time to repeat */
  }
```

You can do the same with the words in the box.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It doesn't work when I click hide (id = "hide"). How to run a reverse animation?

Comment: You just have to repeat everything the other way round. Just change the numbers for the opacity. So that it will be. (from{opacity:1} to{opacity:0}). But create another animation keyframes for that. If you want more info about animation in CSS here is the link [W3 schools css animation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp)

Comment: But note that it is sometimes better to use jquery for that

Comment: Please edit your example to explain this. Another keyframes animation to the same div?

Comment: In the case you want to toggle between to animations you have to use javascript

Comment: Just use jquery's animate method to change the css property of animation.[Jquery animate method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp).in javascript just create a boolean variable and use animate() to change the names of the @keyframes you are using.So that when one animation is on the other is off